# Incorrect response after iteration inside for-loop for findById()

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I had created 2 tables named: groupusermaps and groups. From groupusermaps i am fetching all the groupId and these groupId I am passing in findById() method to fetch all the details related to that groupId inside the for loop.

here is my method in service:

```
getAllGroupsByUserId(userId, callback) {
    var arr = [];
    return sequelize.transaction().then(function(t) {
        return groupUserMapModel.GroupUserMap.findAll({
            where: {
                userId: userId
            },
            transaction: t
        }).then((allGroupsByUserId) => {//from findAll i am getting 2, 1, 4 
groupId
            for (var p in allGroupsByUserId) {
                return 
groupModel.Group.findById(allGroupsByUserId[p].groupId, { transaction: t 
}).then((group) => {
                    arr.push(
                        JSON.stringify(group)
                    );
                });
            }
        }).then(() => {
            callback(arr);
        });
    });
}
```

my controller code:

```
router.get('/controllers/getGroups/user/:userId/groups', (req, res) => {
groupService.getAllGroupsByUserId((req.params.userId), (result) => {
    log.info('Group list: ' + JSON.stringify(result));
});
res.send('Fetched all group list');
});
```

But I am getting an empty array as response from the controller on the console. Is there any way to fix this issue?

Comment: Actually your loop doesn't wait for your query execution... So you have to use promise here to stop looping until query response not come....

Answer (score 0):

```
groupUserMapModel.GroupUserMap.findAll({
  where: {
      userId: userId
  },
  include:[{
        model:groupModel
    }]
})
.then((results) => {
    console.log(results);
})
.catch(err=>{
    console.log(err);
})
//  provided that groupUserMapModel associated to   groupModel
groupUserMapModel.associate = models => {
    groupUserMapModel.belongsTo(models.groupModel, {foreignKey: groupId})
}
```

for more info read about sequelize association